# problem in finding list of files in directory

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I want to retrieve list of all file in a specific folder that included oracle form and menu and report and some txt file...

Do you have any idea how I can retrieve these data in ORACLE form, and insert them into my data block, automatically?

I use oracle form 6.0.

Comment: is it possible in ver6 or not?

Comment: Is the directory on the database server or client ?

Comment: Client I already fix it in an other way. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did something along these lines:

Create an Oracle directory for the directory you want to list:

```
create or replace directory YOURDIR
  as '\path\to\your\directory';
```

Build a temporary table:

```
create global temporary table DIR_LIST
(
  FILENAME VARCHAR2(255),
)
on commit preserve rows;
grant select, insert, update, delete on DIR_LIST to PUBLIC;
```

You'll need a java stored procedure:

```
create or replace and compile java source named dirlist as
import java.io.*;
  import java.sql.*;
  import java.text.*;

  public class DirList
  {
  public static void getList(String directory)
                     throws SQLException
  {
      File dir = new File( directory );
      File[] files = dir.listFiles();
      File theFile;

      for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
      {
          theFile = files[i];
          #sql { INSERT INTO DIR_LIST (FILENAME)
                 VALUES (:theName };
      }
  }

  }
```

And a PL/SQL callable procedure to invoke the java:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_dir_list(pi_directory IN VARCHAR2)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
name 'DirList.getList(java.lang.String)';
```

Finally, calling the procedure get_dir_list inside your form will populate the table with the files in your directory, which you can then read into your form block.

The java code came straight out of a Tom Kyte book (don't recall which one).

EDIT:

Actually, all the code is pretty much lifted from this [AskTom thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584).

Comment: That's exactly where I use it. Once you build it, you call it just like any other stored procedure, it builds the directory list in the temp table, and your form can select from that table.

Comment: I have question out of topic, I am using solaris server, by the above code we can see all the solaris folders, may I know how I can give permission to my solaris user to see my other network server?

Answer (score 7):

There is another interesting approach with external tables that makes it even easier to retrieve such lists without using a Java stored procedure:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/incoming

$ cat >/tmp/incoming/readdir.sh<<eof
#/bin/bash
cd /tmp/incoming/
/bin/ls -1
eof

# test files
$ for i in {1..5}; do touch /tmp/incoming/invoice_no_$RANDOM.pdf; done
```

In SQL*Plus:

```
create or replace directory incoming as '/tmp/incoming';

Directory INCOMMING created.

create table files (filename varchar2(255))
organization external ( 
    type oracle_loader
    default directory incoming
    access parameters (
        records delimited by newline
        preprocessor  incoming:'readdir.sh'
        fields terminated by "|" ldrtrim
    )
location ('readdir.sh')
);
/

Table FILES created.

select * from files;

FILENAME                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FILES_27463.log                                                                 
invoice_no_20891.pdf                                                            
invoice_no_2255.pdf                                                             
invoice_no_24086.pdf                                                            
invoice_no_30372.pdf                                                            
invoice_no_8340.pdf                                                             
readdir.sh                                                                      

 7 rows selected
```

This approach was added in the same [Ask Tom thread](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584#7548394200346478741) as mentioned in the @DCookie's answere.