# view contents of a directory on Database Server

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have access to the Oracle 10g database, but not the Unix server.  I would like to verify that a file exists on the server.  Is there a way to use the "ls" command to view the contents of a directory on the Unix server?  I don't think this is possible, but I want to be sure.

Note the file is located in a "directory" defined in the dba_directories view and my Oracle user (myusername) has Oracle read / write access to the "directory".  This can be verified by looking at the dba_tab_privs view.

Comment: you could try using utl_file.fopen function and catch exception (INVALID_PATH) if file doesnt exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it from pl/sql but you can do it with java.  There is an ask tom article that contains the java code at this link.

[http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584)

Comment: And here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181128/problem-in-finding-list-of-files-in-directory