# oracle external table options

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have an ORACLE EXTERNAL TABLE which loads the files data from a path . 
But the file name which is present in the path will be modified for every 5 minutes only the time stamp of the file will be changed in an regular intervals.
**Sample file name** : 'DATA_**31052017032525**.txt'.

--The highlighted path will be changed in regular intervals.

How can i handle this scenario in the ORACLE EXTERNAL TABLE SCRIPT **instead** of modifying the file name in the script of the oet table for every 5 minutes.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. What you could do is copy your file after it's been modified to a file with a static name, and then base your external table on the static named file. E.g.  `DATA_31052017032525.txt` copied to `DATA_main.txt`, then 5 mins later, `DATA_31052017033025.txt` copied to `DATA_main.txt`, etc. That's assuming you need to keep the file with the timestamp in it, otherwise you'd just rename it back to the static name after it's been modified.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the location property of the external table by running

```
dbms_utility.EXEC_DDL_STATEMENT('alter table TABLENAME location (''DATA_31052017032525.txt'')');
```

In case the seconds change as well you'll have to [search the directory contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181128/problem-in-finding-list-of-files-in-directory) first.